# What do they mean by the expressions "of the same type" highlighted below in [class.derived]/7?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

[[class.derived]/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.derived#7):

> [Note: A base class subobject might have a layout ([basic.stc])
> different from the layout of a most derived object **of the same
> type**. A base class subobject might have a polymorphic behavior
> ([class.cdtor]) different from the polymorphic behavior of a most
> derived object **of the same type**. A base class subobject may be of
> zero size ([class]); however, two subobjects that have the same class
> type and that belong to the same most derived object must not be
> allocated at the same address ([expr.eq]). — end note]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cpp
struct B { /* ... */ };
struct D : B { /* ... */ };

B b;
D d;
```

The base class subobject `B` of `d` may have different layout than the most derived object (`b` here) of the same type (`B`). For example, an implementation may reuse the tail padding of `B` for `D`'s members.

Comment: That is correct. I just didn't see the problem from that point of view.

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for something deeper than the obvious

```
class Animal {} // base
class Mammal : Animal {} // derived
class Dog : Mammal {} // most derived
```

Animal, Dog and Mammal are all type Animal.

Bearing the possibility of multiple inheritance in mind (e.g. you could have another hierarchy containing AquaticOrganism and TerrestrialOrganism and choose to define Dog as both (inheriting from) Mammal and TerrestrialOrganism), the passage is pointing out that a Dog cannot be assumed to have layout "Animal plus stuff" (it might be "TerrestrialOrganism plus...").